react native vision camera dont scan pdf-417 from real documents
I have implemented react native vision camera in my react native 0.75 application.
my objective is to scan tickets, which have the code pdf-417

Following the documentation, and doing some tests, I have been able to verify that the pdf417 scanning works correctly with ios. But with when scann the same document with android it does not read the pdf417 of the sale receipts.
I was doing some tests to solve this problem and it turns out that when creating a pdf417 with few characters, it is possible to read it (page to create pdf417 cognex).
But the problem is that the ballots have a standard that has a lot of characters (it is an Xml with all the data of the ballot, social reason, trade rut, amount, date, etc).
Here is the block I have to do the scanning:
import {Alert, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {useAppState} from '@react-native-community/hooks';
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Camera,
  useCameraDevice,
  useCameraFormat,
  useCameraPermission,
  useCodeScanner,
} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Loader} from '../../components/Loader';
import type {Code} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import {Icon, IconButton} from 'react-native-paper';

export const CameraScreen = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('camera');

  const device = useCameraDevice('back');

  const showCodeAlert = (value: string, onDismissed: () => void): void => {
    console.log('showCodeAlert', value);
    isShowingAlert.current = true;
    Alert.alert('Code Scanned', value, [
      {
        text: 'OK',
        onPress: () => {
          isShowingAlert.current = false;
          onDismissed();
        },
      },
    ]);
  };

  const isShowingAlert = useRef(false);

  const onCodeScanned = useCallback((codes: Code[]) => {
    console.log('onCodeScanned', codes);
    console.log(`Scanned ${codes.length} codes!`);
    const value = codes[0].value;
    console.log('Scanned value:', value);
    if (value == null) {
      return;
    }

    if (isShowingAlert.current) {
      return;
    }

    showCodeAlert(value, () => {
      isShowingAlert.current = false;
    });
    isShowingAlert.current = true;
  }, []);

  /*  const codeScanner = useCodeScanner({
    codeTypes: ['qr', 'ean-13', 'pdf-417', 'aztec', 'codabar'],
    onCodeScanned: onCodeScanned,
  }); */
  const codeScanner = useCodeScanner({
    codeTypes: ['qr', 'ean-13', 'code-128', 'code-39', 'pdf-417'],
    onCodeScanned: onCodeScanned,
  });

  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const appState = useAppState();
  const isActive = isFocused && appState === 'active';
  const {hasPermission, requestPermission} = useCameraPermission();

  const camera = useRef<Camera>(null);

  console.log('CameraScreen::Application::STATUS::AppState', appState);
  console.log('CameraScreen::Application::STATUS::isActive', isActive);

  console.log('cameraScreen::MODE', mode);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasPermission) {
      requestPermission();
    }
  }, [hasPermission]);

  //console.log('has Permission?', hasPermission);

  const onCodeScanPress = () => {
    console.log('code scan pressed');
  };

  if (!hasPermission) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  if (device == null) {
    return (
      <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
        <Text>device error</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      {device != null && (
        <Camera
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          device={device}
          isActive={isActive}
          codeScanner={codeScanner}
          //torch={torch ? 'on' : 'off'}
          enableZoomGesture={true}
        />
      )}

      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 50,
          right: 20,
          padding: 5,
          borderRadius: 10,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        }}>
        <IconButton
          icon={mode === 'camera' ? 'camera' : 'barcode-scan'}
          iconColor="white"
          size={30}
          onPress={() => setMode(mode === 'barcode' ? 'camera' : 'barcode')}
        />
      </View>
      <Pressable
        onPress={onCodeScanPress}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          alignSelf: 'center',
          bottom: 50,
          width: 75,
          height: 75,
          borderRadius: 75,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};


This seems a bug of ML Kit.
The two frame processor plugins can read it without a problem:

vision-camera-zxing
vision-camera-dynamsoft-barcode-reader

Demo app:
https://github.com/tony-xlh/react-native-zxing-mlkit-dynamsoft

thanks Lihang. I'will try with the demo app
